# Redirect https from non www to www

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, nginx

Following were my Nginx server config (not work). I need to redirect https non www to www. So when I visit a  site `https://example.com`, it should redirect me to `https://www.example.com`.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl
    server_name example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}
```

EDIT:
my load balancer:
[image]

I am using AMI Linux running Ruby on Rails app in AWS. Thanks!!

Comment: Is your SSL certificate installed on the Elastic Load Balancer or on your Nginx server?

Answer (score 3):

Please use the below config in your nginx.conf file. Its working fine for me.

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    www.example.com example.com;

       location / {
            index       index.html;
            root        /usr/share/nginx/html;  #the location of your app folder
       }


        if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
            return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
        }

}
```

Comment: In aws you can use Elastic load balancer for ssl redirection. Same issue i have found in my nginx server. I have used ssl inside load balancer intead of using back end server. Back end server only listen 80 port instead of 443.

Comment: Yup, I already setup a load balancer, but the problem i need to redirect `https://travelog.com` to `https://www.travelog.com`

Comment: @d3bug3r.. Then why you listening 443 port .In load balancer you should listen 80 port of your instance for https . Then you can configure the redirection by listening 80 port instead of 443 in your nginx server...By using all these procedure i had fixed my redirection problem from non-www to www

Comment: Check the edit, That's is my load balancer config. Is this config valid?

Comment: So your config above still valid for config of my load balancer?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to redirect GET requests and throw a 405 (Method not allowed) for non-GET requests:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  if ($request_method = GET) {
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
  }
  return 405;
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;

  # locations
}
```

If you want all requests (GET, POST, ...) to be redirected, which is not possible, I suggest that you should try Akshath's method.